# Получить количество уникальных записей в таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

```
date_modify
2017-07-13 14:59:25
2017-07-13 14:33:46
2017-07-13 13:35:13
2017-07-13 09:43:05
2017-07-13 09:24:03
2017-07-13 09:13:40
2017-07-12 17:39:08
2017-07-12 17:33:25
2017-07-12 16:55:58
2017-07-12 16:23:08
2017-07-12 16:22:41
2017-07-12 15:48:35
2017-07-12 15:44:14
2017-07-12 15:38:51
2017-07-12 15:33:58
2017-07-12 15:30:17
2017-07-12 15:20:03
2017-07-12 15:15:57
2017-07-12 15:02:59
2017-07-12 15:02:06
2017-07-12 14:44:11
```

Есть такая таблица, нужно выделить только единичные даты
к примеру чтоб после запроса осталось только это:

```
2017-07-13
2017-07-12
```

Comment: `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_modify, '%Y-%m-%d')` используй)  или `GROUP BY DATE(date_modify)` .....а  вообще из условия непонятно чё ты добиваешься

Comment: Поможешь изменить запрос?
`$query ="SELECT `date_modify` FROM `**` WHERE `product_publish` = '1' ORDER BY `date_modify` DESC LIMIT ".$end.", 15";`

Comment: Как этот запрос относится к вычислению уникальных записей, который почему-то базируется на датах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вы получите уникальные даты:

```
select distinct date(date_modify)
from test
order by 1
```

[Пример 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdf42/1/0).

Так получите количество уникальных дат:

```
select count(distinct date(date_modify))
from test
```

[Пример 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdf42/3/0).

Comment: там ему нужно **количество**. хотя вопрос странный в целом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский меня смутило "чтоб после запроса осталось только это:"